# Amazon EC2 Server - Log-in server with root permission

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I just got a Amazon EC2 Server and noticed that I can only connect to the server with ec2-user account.

This account doesn't have root permission, therefore, I have to use sudo command on SSH to get root permission.

However, I usually edit code on EditPlus or Aptana Studio to change codes in the file.

I successfully connected the server with ec2-user on EditPlus, but couldn't write other folder files.

ec2-user doesn't have root permission when I log in.

Is there a way to give root permission to ec2-user when it signs in?

Comment: I did this one. it worked :)
http://serverfault.com/a/294894

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable Rootlogin in ssh([how](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/security-tip-disable-root-ssh-login-on-linux/)), but it is not a good security practice.. Change the following entry in /etc/ssh/sshd_config file.

```
 PermitRootLogin yes
```

There are two ways you can authenticate the root user in ssh.

1. Keypair
2. Password

Other way would be to save the modified file in ec2-user home and moving it later using sudo.